How to get comparison in years between two dates in the cshtml
I am doing an MVC 6 Application.
I need to get the difference in YEAR between 2 dates in the View.
I have this
Years(Convert.ToDateTime(date1), Convert.ToDateTime(date2))

in the controller. But I need to do something similar in the cshtml
I only could do
var dateC = (Convert.ToDateTime(date2) - Convert.ToDateTime(date1)).Days;

But I get the days.. I could not find the way to return the years.
Taking the years between 2 dates is not the answer I am looking for...
01/01/2019 and 01/01/2018 the difference is 1 year... But 01/01/2019 and 12/12/2018, the difference is not 1 year... and If I take date.Year will return 1 year. What I am looking for is the difference taking Calendar year, not taking the year of both dates
thanks

Does this answer your question? How to get a Timespan of 1 year?

thanks, I add more comments... I need Calendar years.. not taking the difference between those 2 years

So, find the diff in days and determine the number of years based on that.  If you need a precise answer, you'll need to check how many days are in each year between your two dates because not all years have 365 days. This is why TimeSpan only has .Days and not .Years

The question is unclear. Please add some (more) examples explaining what the expected output would be for various inputs. Particularly, if the algorithm should rely on some kind of rounding, specify the rules for rounding up or down.

The description says "I need to get the difference in YEAR between 2 dates "
I need the difference in Years between 2 dates.... 01/01/2020 12/31/1019 return 1 year... but the difference is 0 year, 1 day

Use the Year property:
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2018, 12, 12);
DateTime date2 = new DateTime(2019, 1, 1);

int years = date2.Year - date1.Year;

Console.WriteLine(years.ToString());
1


thanks , but this return the difference between those year.. I need the difference in Years between 2 dates.... 01/01/2020 12/31/1019 return 1 year... but the difference is 0 year, 1 day....

You asked: I am looking for is the difference taking Calendar year, and that is what this does.

It's not clear how you'd like the calculation to handle rounding, leap years, etc., but to start out with a simple (and possibly naive) function, you could do this:
public static int InWholeYears(this TimeSpan timeSpan)
{
    var years = timeSpan.Days / 365.0;
    return (int)Math.Round(years);
}

This just assumes that all years are 365 days, which obviously they aren't. Still, under that assumption, you get a number of years, and then return that number rounded using normal rounding rules.
You can use it like this:
[Fact]
public void QExample()
{
    var duration = new DateTime(2019, 1, 1) - new DateTime(2018, 1, 1);
    var actual = duration.InWholeYears();
    Assert.Equal(1, actual);
}

You can use Math.Floor or Math.Ceiling if you want some other cutoff behaviour.
If you want to make the calculation more sophisticated by taking leap years into account, you can ask your system's current Calendar how many days are in the year of interest.
Again, it's not clear from the OP how a time span between dates in two different years should be handled. Which of the years should be taken into account? What if the dates are 29 years apart?
Thus, since the requirements are unclear, I'll leave that up to your discretion.
